# Bootstrap nav-tabs full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I positioned bootstrap nav-tabs at the bottom of a container using absolute positioning and it worked pretty good with one issue: as soon as I positioned absolute it's not full width of the container anymore.
Here's a picture:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs profile-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile-nav{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.profile-nav .nav-item{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The image container has position: relative in order to position the nav like that. 
So, as I said, the problem is, I can't make it full width of the container fluid.

Comment: Have you tried adding property `width: 100%` to the `.profile-nav` class in your CSS?

Comment: can i have url of that design

Comment: yes, I tried that but it goes 100% on the right side, outside of the container-fluid.. I'm not sure why it does that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix at bottom your nav tabs you need to wrap your items into nav with a bootstrap class `navbar-fixed-bottom`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom profile-nav">
```

I think nav-tabs not best looking form for a bottom menu. Try to use `nav-pills` instead.

Look at snippet

```css
.profile-nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: none;
}

.profile-nav .nav-item {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom profile-nav">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `left: 0;` & `width: 100%;` to `.profile-nav`

```css
.profile-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* add these */
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.profile-nav .nav-item {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs profile-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be this will help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .profile-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* add these */
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.profile-nav .nav-item {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs profile-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```